# Elementos html sobre video a pantalla completa

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, videojs, video-adaptativo

Se trata de una duda teorica. Tengo una aplicación heredada, la cual entre otras cosas muestra un video sobre un iframe de vimeo. Y sobre el video se van mostrando preguntas y botones para la respuesta en la parte baja mediante un div. 
Todo esto funciona bien mientras el video NO esté a pantalla completa. 
Mi pregunta es si se pueden superponer elementos html sobre un video a pantalla completa, en que elemento DOM se reproduce el video??

Agradezco cualquier tipo de orientación, llevo ya un tiempo investigando pero cero resultados validos.

Comment: Deberías poner un ejemplo de lo que has intentado, para hacer la pregunta más clara

Answer (score -1):

En lugar de pedir la pantalla completa para un vídeo, pídelo para el contenedor del vídeo.

Te pongo un ejemplo a continuación, pero por algún motivo no termina de funcionar en la web de SOes, así que aquí tienes el mismo código funcionando en [codepen](https://codepen.io/pawer13/pen/xzEewy)

```js
const container=document.getElementById('container');
const button=document.getElementById('full');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {      
  container.webkitRequestFullscreen();
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width:400px;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
}
video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  background-color: #0000FF99;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="container">
    <span>TEXTO</span>
    <video controls  src="https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4"
    poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/title_anouncement.jpg?x11217" />
  </div>
</div>
<button id="full">Click</button>
```